# i have error in android studio with kotlin

Tags: android, error-handling, kotlin

why this error?

09-12 16:36:31.502 1886-1886/com.getloction.nourmedhat.smartgate.getlocation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.getloction.nourmedhat.smartgate.getlocation, PID: 1886
            kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String
            at com.getloction.nourmedhat.smartgate.getlocation.All_Station$onCreate$2.onDataChange(All_Station.kt:56)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: post your code, where you are facing the problem

Comment: Log explains pretty clear: **TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin**

Comment: It says that your `String` is `null`. You should declare it as `String?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by AlexTa you're getting a `TypeCastException` because you cast `null` to a non-null type.

In Kotlin types are "@NotNull" by default. So if you declare a variable like this:

```
var yourVar: String
```

you cannot assign null to it. If it should be capable of storing `null` (which it often shouldn't) you declare it like this:

```
var yourVar: String? = null
```